# Derivative of theta, exponential parametrization

Tags: complex-analysis

In [Using the Residue Theorem to Prove that $\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{1}{(a+\cos\theta)^{2}} d \theta=\frac{2\pi a}{(a^{2}-1)^{3/{2}}}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971501/using-the-residue-theorem-to-prove-that-int2-pi-0-frac1a-cos-theta), they define z = $e^{i\theta}$ and claim that d$\theta$ = $\frac{1}{iz}$. I'm confused by how they get that value for $d\theta$?

Edit: From the formula, we get iz $d\theta$ = 1. So we have iz $d\theta$ = $ie^{i\theta} d\theta$ = $-e^{i\theta}$. I don't see how this is equal to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contour $|z|=1$ is parameterized with $\gamma(\theta) = e^{i \theta}$, $0 \le \theta \le 2  \pi$. Then
$$
 \gamma'(\theta) = i e^{i \theta} = i \gamma(\theta)
$$
and therefore
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \theta})  \, d\theta = 
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{f(\gamma(\theta))}{i\gamma(\theta)} \gamma'(\theta) \, d\theta =
 \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{iz} \, dz 
$$
for continuous (or integrable) functions on the unit circle. This substitution is shortly written as
$$
 z = e^{i \theta} \, ,  dz = i e^{i \theta} d\theta = i z \, d\theta
$$
and the last equation is rearranged to $ d\theta = \frac{1}{iz} dz$.

(The $dz$ term was missing in the referenced post, that has been fixed now.)